# Как развернуть и свернуть CardView в Android?

Tags: android, transition, cardview

Видел как много людей использует CardView, как пример:
В закрытом виде
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В открытом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не могу понять каким образом его так развернуть и свернуть. Прошу помощи или примера кода.

P.S. Вроде как слышал, что делается с помощью Transition

Comment: Создайте два `CardView` и изменяйте их видимость. А анимации переходов между ними можно сделать с помощью `MaterialContainerTransform`

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего использовать уже готовую библиотеку по типу ExpandableView

[Expandable RecyclerView](https://github.com/hendraanggrian/recyclerview-expandable)

[ExpandableView](https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/ExpandableView)

Про transition хорошо описано [на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/243363/) но как по мне это не подходящее решение для развертывания карточки

Второй вариант это упаковать LinearLayout с аттрибутом `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` в CardView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/block1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/block2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

и при клике показывать/скрывать block2

Вариант по сложней это рисовать свою анимацию изменения размера как показано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41465563/7540461)

Answer (score 1):

Как я написал в комментарии, чтобы это сделать можно создать два `CardView` в айтеме, если это раскрывающийся список(если нет - то еще проще). По нажатию менять видимость, а анимации прикрутить с помощью `MaterialContainerTransform`.

Вот работающий пример:

`Activity`:

```
class ExpActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exp)

    exp_recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
    exp_recycler.adapter = ExpAdapter(getItems()) { startView, endView, 
    rootLayout ->
        beginDelayedTransition(rootLayout, startView.getTransform(endView))
    }
}

private fun getItems() = listOf(
    Item(1, "Title1", getString(R.string.dummy_text)),
    Item(2, "Title2", getString(R.string.dummy_text)),
    Item(3, "Title3", getString(R.string.dummy_text)),
    Item(4, "Title4", getString(R.string.dummy_text))
)

private fun View.getTransform(mEndView: View) = 
MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
    startView = this@getTransform
    endView = mEndView
    addTarget(mEndView)
    pathMotion = MaterialArcMotion()
    duration = 550
    scrimColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
}
}
```

`Adapter`:

```
class ExpAdapter(
private val items: List<Item>,
private val clickListener: (View, View, ConstraintLayout) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ExpAdapter.ExpViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = 
ExpViewHolder(
    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_exp, parent, false)
)

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ExpViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = items[position]

    with(holder) {
        shortText.text = item.shortText
        longText.text = item.longText

        shortCard.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener(shortCard, longCard, rootLayout)
            shortCard.visibility = GONE
            longCard.visibility = VISIBLE
        }

        longCard.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener(longCard, shortCard, rootLayout)
            longCard.visibility = GONE
            shortCard.visibility = VISIBLE
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemCount() = items.size

class ExpViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val rootLayout: ConstraintLayout = view.root_layout
    val shortText: TextView = view.short_text
    val longText: TextView = view.long_text
    val shortCard: CardView = view.short_card
    val longCard: CardView = view.long_card
}
}
```

Макет айтема:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/short_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/short_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:text="@string/heading_text" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/long_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/long_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:text="@string/dummy_text" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```